# Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax

I use the Microsoft ASP.Net AJAX framework for an autocompletion thingy on a text field (AutoCompleteExtender).

I'm getting an error :

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property.

Several weird things about this error :

- the error is thrown even when every single webservice in my solution return nothing (I altered them to return empty arrays) ;
- in the web.config, jsonSerialization maxJsonLength is set to the maximum value of 2147483644, and the webservices in this page are supposed to return a few results ;
- it says the source of the error is in a javascript function, but the function is never run, so the webservice is never actually called :
- when I delete every AutoCompleteExtender and every call to any webservice from the page, it starts to throw me errors on "end if" inside the aspx. When I remove every "If" in the aspx, it crashes without telling me why. Fun !

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tbEntrIdFonctionItemSelected = function(sender, e) {
       $get('<%=Me.FormViewContact.FindControl("hdn_AgenceIdFonctionSearch").ClientID%>').value = e.get_value(); // source of the error
    }
</script>
```

What do you think could be the cause of the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I think that this article can give you some suggestions. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after a bit of tracking, I noticed that a Telerik Combobox was the source of the error. And apparently, it was retreiving (using JSON, hence the error) the very small amount of 140.000 items. No big deal, right ? Hum.

Comment: Well, actually the Telerik Combobox was not supposed to retreive 140.000 items. I fixed that (it returned a few doze items), and it worked. If you have the same problem, try deactivating every third-party component on your page, or check the length of dropdowns and such. Something on your page is retreiving far too many items using JSON ; find out what it is.